# GridSearchCV in scikit-learn(sklearn): TypeError: 'KFold' object is not iterable

Tags: scikit-learn, svm, cross-validation, grid-search

I'm trying to find best values of C & gamma for SVR() estimator using GridSearchCV() but I get this error

TypeError: 'KFold' object is not iterable

This the code

```
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
C_range = np.logspace(-2, 10, 13)
gamma_range = np.logspace(-9, 3, 13)
param_grid = dict(gamma=gamma_range, C=C_range)
cv = KFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=False, random_state=None)
grid = GridSearchCV(SVR(kernel='rbf'), param_grid=param_grid, cv=cv)
grid.fit(X, y)

print("The best parameters are %s with a score of %0.2f"
  % (grid.best_params_, grid.best_score_))
```

Answer (score 6):

**Similar problem solved by:**

**Replacing:**

```
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
```

**with**

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
```

Answer (score 1):

`cv` is an object in your case.
You should use `KFold` in order to create batches of data, and pass these batches to `GridSearchCV` in `cv` argument.

Here an example on how to create splits, using `KFold`:

```
>>> from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
>>> X = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2], [3, 4]])
>>> y = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> kf = KFold(n_splits=2)
>>> kf.get_n_splits(X)
2
>>> print(kf)  
KFold(n_splits=2, random_state=None, shuffle=False)
>>> for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X):
...    print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
...    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
...    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
TRAIN: [2 3] TEST: [0 1]
TRAIN: [0 1] TEST: [2 3]
```